# Spring MVC - respecting double slash in REST request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, backslash

Lets say I have the following two REST endpoints built with Spring MVC (v.4):

```
 1. [GET] /cars/make/{make}
 2. [GET] /cars/make/{make}/model
```

And the following requests:

```
 1. curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost/cars/make//model"
 2. curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" "http://localhost/cars/make/%20/model"
```

The two requests will match the first endpoint (with path variable `make` having a value of `model`. Is it possible to change the matcher to match on the second endpoint with `make` being an empty string or whitespace?

I've been able to override the default Spring `AntPathMatcher` to not trim tokens, thus fixing the issue with the second request. However I'm not sure how to modify it so that it strictly respects the 2 backslashes with no whitespace in between. Is this possible?